# Please could there be a ... after the tag wiki on the tag page?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki

Here the tag wiki just cuts off, with no warning:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Please could it have an ellipsis, like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

Update: I just found (from web inspector) that it does have an ellipsis, just in the wrong place:

```
<div class="excerpt">
  **DO NOT USE THIS TAG**. Use either [tag:system-installation] (for system installs) or [tag:software-installation] (for installing software on a running system). Questions about installing Ubuntu, or …
</div>
```

When it needs to be here:

```
<div class="excerpt">
  **DO NOT USE THIS TAG**. Use either [tag:system-installation] (for system installs) or [tag:software-installation] (for...
</div>
```